# Custom format that depends on cell value

Tags: microsoft-excel

I'd like to have some cells displayed according to the following rule (let `x` be cell value):

```
x = 0        -> string "FLOOR"
0 < x < 1    -> percentage (e.g. "53%")
x = 1        -> string "CAP"
x > 1        -> currency (e.g. "$ 4,512.96")
```

Is there a way to accomplish this preferrably without VBA? I'm in the end of a complex spreadsheet and up to now have been able to avoid using `Worksheet.Change`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can achieve it with conditional formatting:
[image]
For 1 and 0 use custom number format with `"CAP"` and `"FLOOR"` description, percentage and currency are also set through number formats.

Comment: So obvious, but the initial screen of Conditional Formatting definitely threw me off with its colors and scales. Every time I have to use CF I'm forced to relearn the "New Rule" dialog. Thanks Máté!